# Methods on Angular2 class not being recognized

Tags: angular, class, typescript

I have the following class in Angular2:

```js
export class MyClass{

constructor(private a: string, private b: string, private c: string){}

    public getA(): string {
        return this.a;
    }

    public getB(): string {
        return this.b;
    }

    public getC(): string{
        return this.c;
    }
```

I am then using this object in another component:

```js
MyClass myClass = new MyClass('some', 'thing', 
let path = myClass.getA() != null ? 'foo' :'bar';
```

However, trying to run on the browser I get the following error in the console:

`ERROR TypeError: myClass.getA is not a function`

Am I missing something? In order to correct this, the only way I've found was to declare the variables public (it also works with private, but my IDE - VS Code - indicates an error) and use them directly without the accessor methods.

Comment: Note that if you want getters and setters TypeScript has `get` and `set` accessor syntax: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors

Comment: sorry @PankajParkar, it was a typo... I added a function that writes to the console and I still get the same error...

Comment: I tried this, just doing console.log(myClass.getA()) and it worked. the typo in your question where you didnt complete the MyClass('some', 'thing','else) is in your source code too? One thing, are you actually newing up the MyClass is your source code? or is it coming from the server or something? if you don't new up the object yourself, I think it wont actually have access to the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax (Java?) to declare the variable myClass. It should go like this:

```
const myClass:MyClass = new MyClass('some', 'thing', 'fff'); 
let path = myClass.getA() != null ? 'foo' :'bar';
```

Answer (score -1):

May be something like this... I suppose.

```
    class MyClass {
    private a: string;
    private b: string;
    private c: string;  //<-------

constructor(private a: string, private b: string, private c: string) {    }

public getA(): string {         return this.a;    }
public getB(): string {        return this.b;    }
public getC(): string {        return this.c;    }
}

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass('some', 'thing', 'an');
    let path = myClass.getA() != null ? 'foo' : 'bar';
    console.log(path);
```

`

Result : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ gived foo as expected.

Comment: Adding the accessibility modifier makes the constructor arguments [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties).